# Trouble with Python JSON input from STDIN

Tags: json, python-3.x, stdin

```
input = json.load(sys.stdin)
print(input['id'])
```

When I input {"id":1} and hit enter, my program does not continue, I am just stuck typing in my input. How can I make the program continue after valid json has been passed to my stdlin?

Comment: You have to close the file. On Linux and other Unix-like systems you do that by hitting Ctrl-D. I think on Windows you need Ctrl-Z, but I don't know much about Windows.

Comment: BTW, you forgot to include the `import` statements in your code. And don't use `input` as a variable name, that shadows the built-in `input` function.

Comment: To be perfectly clear - this is a BUG in the python library. Its perfectly clear when the end of a JSON object is parsing (only one character lookahead needed). Some JSON parsing libraries (c++) do this correctly, and so the above usage - reading from stdin - would work just fine; this reader <https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/v2.1b9/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/DataExchange/Variant/JSON/Reader.cpp> only looks ahead one character at most to find end of JSON.

Comment: This is not a bug. `json.load` takes an open file and reads its whole contents, and the documentation states that it uses `read()` to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you read in from `sys.stdin` it will read everything until it hits an EOF character normally ctrl-d so if you input `{"id":1} <ENTER> ctrl-d` it should work.

It looks like what you are trying to do is something like this

```
import json
json_as_str = input()
json_obj = json.loads(json_as_str)
print(json_obj['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code interactively by pasting the two lines in and then realised the second line was being interpreted as part of the JSON the first line was reading! As a module the code works perfectly predictably. The visible input was followed by a newline and CTRL/D on the console.

```
sholden$ cat /tmp/py.py
import json, sys
input = json.load(sys.stdin)
print(input['id'])
sholden$ python /tmp/py.py
{"id": 42}
42
```