# Input prompt won't end

Tags: python, python-3.x

Running Python 3.6.5

I'm very new to python. When I run these lines separately in the terminal, I get exactly what I want. When I run the python file, the input prompt 'ideal weight?' won't end after I submit a number. It keeps repeating 'ideal weight?'. I'm trying to find the combination of numbers from the 'weights' set that will sum up to the user input.

```
import itertools
weights = [3, 3, 7.5, 7.5, 10]
weightint = int(input('ideal weight? '))
result = [seq for i in range(len(weights), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(weights, i) if sum(seq) == weightint]
print(result)
```

Can someone help explain what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Your code seems to work for me... Perhaps try a different terminal to execute the code.

Comment: what is your python file name?

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf weight.py

Comment: and how do you run it?

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf python3 /.weight.py

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf The file opens fine. It just gets stuck on repeating the prompt 'ideal weight?'

Comment: works fine for me on `zsh` or `bash`: ```python3 ./weight.py 
ideal weight? 10
[(10,)]```

Comment: what is your shell / OS?

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf /bin/bash OSX 10.11

Comment: would it quit if you hit `CTRL^D` after entering the number? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180360/trouble-with-python-json-input-from-stdin

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf Getting an error if I do that. EOFError.

Comment: can you also try openieng a new terminal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197891/how-to-handle-eoferror-for-raw-input-in-python-in-mac-os-x ?

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf I can open a terminal that way.

Comment: I mean try the ctrl-d trick in a new terminal

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf I get the same result. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: urw, im running out of ideas of why termianl doesn't work. Consider answer below as a workaround.

Comment: Your code works for me. I'm using CMD on Windows 7. :P

Comment: Nothing about this code would repeat the input prompt.  Are you sure this is the __exact__ code you're running?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whats wrong with your terminal. Consider using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead of `input`:

```
import itertools
import argparse

MY_WEIGHTS = [3, 3, 7.5, 7.5, 10]

def find_weight(w):
    result = [seq for i in range(len(MY_WEIGHTS), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(MY_WEIGHTS, i) if sum(seq) == w]
    return result

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-w', '--weight', required=True, type=int, help='The weight')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    result = find_weight(args.weight)
    print('result: {}'.format(result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then call it from command line with `--weight` or `-w`:

```
python3 ./weight.py --weight 10

result: [(10,)]
```